# How to set-up script for Animation

Tags: jquery, animation

How would you set up a jquery script that would cycle through some list items and add/remove classes from them on timed delay

```
<ul>
<li></li><!-- the class ".jump" is added for 3 seconds then the class is removed -->
<li></li><!-- the class ".jump" is added for 1.5 seconds then the class is removed -->
<li></li><!-- the class ".jump" is added for 2 seconds then the class is removed -->
<li></li><!-- the class ".jump" is added for 1 seconds then the class is removed -->
<li></li><!-- the class ".jump" is added for 5 seconds then the class is removed -->
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `data-` property and a little Javascript:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li data-delay="3000">hello</li>
    <li data-delay="1500">World!</li>
    <li data-delay="2000">Foo</li>
    <li data-delay="1000">Bar</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {
    var $items = $('ul li').addClass('jump');

    $items.each(function() {
        var $self = $(this);

        setTimeout(function() {
            $self.removeClass('jump');
        }, $self.data('delay'));
    });
});
```

**demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bM6uY/5/